# HTMLWorker.parseToList ignores background color

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I'm using java i text for generating pdf. Some data in my pdf is from html. I'm using `HTMLWorker.parseToList` to create it.

My problem is that it ignores the background color that is written inside the html tags. Any idea why? How can i solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of iText are you using?  How are you setting the background color?

Comment: @Mark Storer: I'm using itext 5.0.6 , and i'm not setting the background, the text i want to be created in the pdf is the text i get from from tinymce text editor.

Comment: Okay... let me try again:  How is the background color being defined in the first place?

Comment: @Mark Storer: The background is defined like this: "background: #ff9900;" . I can't control how it's defined - the text editor generates it automatically.

Answer (score 4):

Spotty CSS Support strikes again.

iText doesn't currently support the `backgroundcolor` style.  It does support the `bgcolor` attribute however, and attributes and styles are mapped into the same namespace.

So if you XSLT your incoming HTML, you could add a matching bgcolor attribute, or simply change the style string to `bgcolor`.

Ugly, but effective.

---

iText's HTML->PDF conversion code is supposed to get a major upgrade in the next release.  The groundwork was laid in the 5.0.6 release, though I haven't seen any code changes that will actually improve the output as yet.

Comment: thank's for your help. i replaced all "backgroundcolor" versions inside my html code and changed it to "bgcolor" , but it still not working for me - I can't see the background in the generated pdf.. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this text only and it also did not work : text = "<span style=\"bgcolor: #ffff00;\">Highlighted Information</span>";" am I doing somthing wrong? how should I write it? thank's.

Comment: The only real option left is to Get The Source and Step Through It.  Good hunting.

Comment: Still no background-color support :)

Answer (score 2):

It works with bgcolor when used as a direct attribute (but not in style attribute with "background-color")

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2">
  <tr bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
    <td><b>Gray Header</b></td>
    <td><b>Second header</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:green">Green text</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFC0C0">Red background</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below workaround and it perfectly works for me.

```
.tr-bg{
        background-color: #D3D3D3;
      }
```

And use this class for required dom element.